# Creating completion handler function for addDocument(Firebase) function

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to swift and my friend suggested me to use completion handler functions so I would easily change them in one place when I would like to change from using Firebase to other APIs. Can you help with finding out, how should I write this correctly and maybe explain how does it work?

```
self.addDocument(data: [fullname, username, result!.user.uid]) {Error in
                        if Error != nil {
                            self.showError("Error saving user's data")
                        }
                    }

func addDocument(data: [String], completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil) -> <#Return Type#> {
        //storing his fullname and username
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
        return db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
                "fullname": data[0],
                "username": data[1],
                "uid": data[2]
        ]) { (error) in
            
        } as! Error
    }
```

Comment: rather than re-hash and re-explain the subject, you could have a look at existing explanations, such as:  

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/

https://programmingwithswift.com/understanding-completion-handlers-in-swift/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/preventing_timing_problems_when_using_closures